# Sonar showing wrong Language in UI for multi language applications

Tags: sonarqube, multilingual

For sonar multi language + multi module projects, sonar main dashboard is showing the language as default language java.

For e.g we've a project with cpp and python components, which onboarded through sonar-runner. In sonar dashboard, language is showing as java at dashboard level. Individual components are showing right language. Can sonar show list of languages which are analyzed in respective project?

```
7450-CPP-PYTHON-GlobalNet
Key:    com.GlobalNet:Glo
**Language:     Java**
Profile:    Java 2010 (version 6)

sonar.projectName=7450-GlobalNet
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.projectDescription=7450-CPP-PYTHON-GlobalNet
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.modules=cpp,python

python.sonar.projectBaseDir=${WORKSPACE}/vobs/phase2_proj/phase2/
python.sonar.modules=autys_jil,pythonScripts
python.sources=.
python.sonar.language=py

cpp.sonar.projectBaseDir=${WORKSPACE}/vobs/phase2_proj/phase2/
cpp.sonar.sources=src/batchCalc,src/calc
```

SonarQuebe version: 4.0

Answer (score 2):

Latest versions of SonarQube "remove" this concept of one project = one language or one module = one language. You should give a try to the latest version of SonarQube and run the analysis without setting the sonar.language property. Each analysis is now a multi-language analysis.

Comment: Thanks David, Upgrading to new version is in our pipeline. But will that new version show all the languages in main dashboard?

Comment: Yes, it will. See http://nemo.sonarqube.org/dashboard/index/48569 for example. The project contains Java, JavaScript and XML files.